# Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, node-gyp

I am trying to run an API. I get this error. I have uninstalled node modules, reinstalled, npm rebuild. I tried to install memwatch but that also gives errors. I have tried doing all types of restarts and reboots.
I have to use Node 8.11.1 for this project, so I cannot change the version. Here is the complete error:

```
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION 
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jackc\Documents\GitHub\blacqmarket\api\node_modules\memwatch-next
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm WARN genstore-api@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
npm ERR! memwatch-next@0.3.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the memwatch-next@0.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jackc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-09T11_35_46_516Z-debug.log
```

Comment: any news on this?

Answer (score 6):

it seems there an issue in olders npm, you could try first by `npm install -g npm@latest`, if this not work or you are not able to upgrade your node.js version, try by doing this

```
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -g
```

Comment: I had a different path: `npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`

Answer (score 2):

I had the errors below on Windows 11:

NPM:

> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT

Visual Studio:

> spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT

[image]

This configuration was correct for me with BuildTools 2019 and Windows 11:

```
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -g
```

Comment: It work for me on Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

If you are done with Visual Studio 2019 and have moved on to Visual Studio 2022 you can try this solution.  I had build tools for Visual Studio 2017, 2019, and 2022. I uninstalled visual studio 2019 and its corresponding build tools and that fixed the issue.  Note: After uninstalling the 2019 visual studio and the 2019 build tools that 2019 folder should be empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only thing that worked on Windows 11 was specifying the build path manually (use yours):

```
npm install hnswlib-node --msbuild_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```